# How can I write a text file (txt) into my ftp server?

Tags: java

How can i do that? Who can help me please?
I tried all the Apache plugins but it DOESN'T work!
Do you know any plugin that can help me to write txt file and write them to my FTP server?
My pleasure. (srry my english is not gud at all)

Comment: Hi NotTran, welcome at Stackoverflow. I think to get a satisfying answer you should improve your question: 1. state your question without noise such as "Who can help me please?". 2. If you have "tried all the Apache plugins" you should give more insights on what you tried and where your stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, You can not write file directly on FTP. You need to write it locally then store it on FTP. Try this, it works for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String server = "ftp://ftp.dlptest.com/";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "dlpuser@dlptest.com";
    String pass = "fLDScD4Ynth0p4OJ6bW6qCxjh";

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {

        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        File firstLocalFile = new File("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Book1.xlsx");

        String firstRemoteFile = "Book1.xlsx";
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);

        System.out.println("Start uploading first file");
        boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        if (done) {
            System.out.println("The first file is uploaded successfully.");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What plugin does that code use?

Comment: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient